# combine the output of two tables has same structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have two tables stuff and employee

```
Stuff
ID   F_Name   L_Name
1    Charles  Nilson
2    Bell      Steve


employee
ID   F_Name   L_Name
231  Andy      natalie
622  Mego      Rob
127  Roberto   Bell
```

I would like to display them as following

```
Stuff_employee
ID   F_Name    L_Name
1    Charles   Nilson
2    Bell      Steve
231  Andy      natalie
622  Mego      Rob
127  Roberto   Bell
```

Does any one have any idea how to do that?
you suggestions or thought will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: UNION but it didn't give me what I needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM `Stuff`
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM `employee`
```

Read more about [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM Stuff UNION ALL SELECT * FROM employee
```